# Named-pipe-wrapper library working example

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I require a working example of how to use the [Named-Pipe-Wrapper] Library v1.4 in a simple client and server implementation.

I'm having difficulty getting the [Named-Pipe-Wrapper](https://github.com/acdvorak/named-pipe-wrapper) library v1.4 to send/receive messages between 1 client and the server. 
I can see that my client has connected, but messages sent between the client and the server are not coming through.

What am I doing wrong?

I chose this library as it seemed easy to pass strongly typed objects between client and server without having to handle serializing and deserializing said objects.

Here is the code I put together for testing purposes below.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var server = new NamedPipeServer<Message>("MyPipe");
        server.ClientConnected += delegate (NamedPipeConnection<Message, Message> conn)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client {0} is now connected!", conn.Id);
        };
        server.ClientMessage += 
            delegate (NamedPipeConnection<Message, Message> conn, Message message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client {0} message received !", conn.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Client {0} says: {1}", conn.Id, message.Text);
            conn.PushMessage(new Message() { Text = "HELLO from server" });
        };
        server.Start();

        var client = new NamedPipeClient<Message>("MyPipe");
        client.ServerMessage += 
            delegate (NamedPipeConnection<Message, Message> conn, Message message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server says: {0}", message.Text);
        };
        client.Start();
        //client.WaitForConnection(1000);            
        client.PushMessage(new Message() { Text = "HELLO from client" });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Message
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

**Update**
If I use native data types this works, however when I use simple classes with native types it doesn't work.

**Update 2**
The code I had put together was sound but required that I add the [serializable] attribute on the Message class.

Comment: Have you tried **debugging** your code?

Comment: Yes, I only get notification that the client has connected. No messages are coming through. Are you seeing something different to this ?

Comment: Are you sure that the Named Pipes services are running?

Comment: I've corrected and simplified the code. I am working off two separate projects before, one server and one client, and put this code together for stackoverflow devs to replicate the result I am getting easily. 
After the changes, my results are still the same. 
I will try the older versions of this library next.

Comment: Kindly motivate your down vote for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Message class requires the [serializable] attribute.

Comment: This did the trick.